# Second 'the' in the 'The Age of the Cathedrals' song title

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-articles

Why does the famous song 'The Age of **the** Cathedrals' from the Notre-Dame de Paris musical have the second article 'the'? Shouldn't it be titled 'The Age of Cathedrals'?

Comment: Poor translation from French? To make the lyrics fit the music?

Comment: Why should it not have the second "the"?  It is presumably referring to some specific cathedrals, not all cathedrals throughout the Universe.

Comment: The first *The* is a determiner for *Age*, while the second *the* is a determiner for *Cathedrals*. It is certainly acceptable to include **or** omit the second *the*, and the difference is subtle--perhaps even indistinguishable to some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me disagree with all the answers so far. It ***should*** be titled *The Age of Cathedrals*.

The French indeed has ***of the*** cathedrals (***des*** cathédrales), but French definite articles behave slightly differently than English ones. A more faithful translation would be *The Age of Cathedrals.*

Note that if you wanted to use *"the age of cathedrals"* in the lyrics, you would have to change a lot more than just dropping *the*, because if you dropped this syllable, the lyrics wouldn't fit the music. The music has an iambic stress, and  *"the age of cathedrals"* cannot be fit into an iambic rhythm.

> Il **est** ve**nu** le **temps** des **ca**thé**dra**les.
>   From **no**where **came** the **age** of **the** ca**the**drals

And, as the other answers say, *the age of the cathedrals* is not actually wrong in English, it just has a slightly different meaning than *the age of cathedrals*.

Comment: Even if there is a consistent difference in English, wouldn't both "of cathedrals" and "of the cathedrals"  be translated in French as "des cathédrales"? If so, how can you tell which English expression is more faithful to the French?

Comment: @sumelic: yes, they'd both be translated into French that way. But if you look at the French lyrics, they don't seem to be talking about any specific cathedrals but cathedrals in general.

Comment: Well, I think the use of the definite article in English doesn't always imply specificity. What about "the age of the dinosaurs"? I would interpret that as referring to dinosaurs in general, not any particular group of them.

Answer (score 1):

Using the definite article adds emphasis to the noun in question. I am unfamiliar with the musical, but if the title is in reference to a particular group of cathedrals, like the ones in Notre-Dame, compared to *all* cathedrals, this article would be a helpful qualifier.

Adding the definitive article is like saying "this specific set of cathedrals" rather than just "some cathedrals".